# Load different DIV content based on what's appended to the URL

Tags: javascript

I feel there is such an easy answer to this, but my google-fu is failing me.  What I currently have are several links that once clicked, change the HTML content in a DIV.

```
<a href="#new" onclick="document.getElementById('body').innerHTML
= '<p>NEW</p>';">NEW!</a>
```

But I want to be able to link to this content.  Is there anyway to link to this by going to a URL such as www.blahblah.com/index.html#new so it auto-loads the new HTML code?

Forgive me if I'm an idiot... I'm fairly new to javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window.location.hash to see what the hash is on the URL and show the correct DIV based on that.  Assuming all your divs are on the page, once you know the div you want to show you would do something like this:

```
document.getElementById(idOfDivToShow).style.display='block';
```

Small example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function loadDiv() {
        if(window.location.hash == '#div1')
          document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block";
        else if(window.location.hash == '#div2')
          document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="loadDiv()">
    <div style="display:none" id="div1">div1</div>
    <div style="display:none" id="div2">div2</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works wonderfully, however, whenever I link to www.blahblahblah.com/index.html#div1 it automatically jumps the page down to the div.  I was playing around with scrollTop, but that doesn't seem to be helping me at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, Mootools, or Prototype you could use [history.js](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history-js) which allows you to set up states with specific content depending on the hash.

Comment: Also see https://gist.github.com/854622 for drop-in script to do the ajax and content swapping for you